# The header of wav audio file contains data fileds of both big endian and little endian type, why?

Tags: wav, endianness

The way data is stored and manipulated depends on the hardware and in this way it is automatically pre-set to be either little endian only or big endian only. Looking at the header of a wav file I can see that some fields are little endian while others are big endian. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The fields that contain string in the header are big endian. All others are little endian.